# How to upload multiple files using ajax one after another? After one file completes uploading start uploading the next?

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, file-upload, promise, axios

I have an array of files. I want to make post request to an API to upload the files one after another. Tried a lot but can't make anything work. The backend handles single file upload at a time.

The code is something like this:

```
function onDropUpload(event) {
    let entries= event.dataTransfer.items;
    let f = new FormData();
    async uploadfile(file) {
         let response = await axios.post('/',file, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}})
         resolve(response);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
         f.append('file_to_save', entries[i]);
         uploadfile(f);
         f.delete('file_to_save');
    }
}
```

The implementation could be far from this (this is just to illustrate the idea). But thing is, I want to start uploading a file after resolving previous file's upload promise.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a new FileData object for each upload

```
function onDropUpload(event){
    let entries= event.dataTransfer.items;
    async uploadfile(file){
         let response = await axios.post('/',file, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}})
         resolve(response);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
         let f = new FormData();
         f.append('file_to_save', entries[i]);
         uploadfile(f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I figured if I loop ->append each file to same formdata and await uploadfile() then clear form data. Also works. I don't know which one is more efficient.